# Responsive site works on desktop, but on mobile device does not load correct styles

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

First time asking here, so hope I'm in the right place.

Below is a site I am working on, (didn't build it) and I thought I'd just test it on my iPhone, but discovered the 'responsive-ness' does not work properly.

When you re-size the browser on a desktop, it works great as it should, but on a mobile/tablet it loads the full desktop styles - strangely if you rotate to landscape and back again it re-loads the correct stylesheet.

There are three style sheets: Desktop, tablet and mobile - a bit of jquery seems to switch between them based on device width.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! :)

http://weybridge-dental-care.co.uk/

Thank you!

```
<!-- Resolution switcher -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://weybridge-dental-care.co.uk/wp-content/themes/weybridge/resolution-switcher.js'></script>

<!-- Disable viewport zoom -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

And this is the js:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
width = parseInt(width);
if (width >= 1000) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "http://www.weybridge-dental-care.co.uk/wp-content/themes/weybridge/styles-desktop.css");
} else if ((width >= 701) && (width <= 999)) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "http://www.weybridge-dental-care.co.uk/wp-content/themes/weybridge/styles-tablet.css");
} else {
   $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "http://www.weybridge-dental-care.co.uk/wp-content/themes/weybridge/styles-mobile.css"); 
}
}

$(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
$(window).resize(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
});
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code the code that is doing the responsive switch here? instead of having us hunt for it at the website?

Comment: could you isolate the problematic sections of code and possibly post them here? otherwise we're left with debugging a whole site based on this description...

Comment: I have edited my orginal post to include details. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your approach simply won't work -- you're altering the href of a stylesheet *after* it's been loaded and applied. Media queries are the correct and supported way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the following tag inside your `<head>`, near the top:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If you're using jQuery to switch between the style sheets, you're not really "responsive," as you're leaving users who have JavaScript turned off out in the cold. [Media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) are the best way to implement this. If you need to support IE<8, which doesn't have native media query support, add the popular [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) plugin to your code.

I use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for responsive designs and can't recommend it enough.

Comment: Hi, this is already in the header.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
Ideally I would use media queries, but it would mean re-doing the style sheet which I'm trying to avoid if I can.

Thanks